# Add mutiple whitelist IP to bypass a htaccess protected directory

Tags: .htaccess, ip, whitelist

I am currently protecting my admin with a htaccess popup but I added a whitelist for my own IP. This is working great:

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '84.x.x.x'">
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/x/domains/my.x.com/.htpasswd/public_html/x/.htpasswd
AuthName "no public access"
require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
</If>
```

Now there are two other locations I would like to whitelist. Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out the syntax for adding multiple IP's. Most examples seem to use older syntax without the if statements.

Does anyone know how I rewrite this code to include 2 additional IP's?

Comment: I would expect that you can use the OR operator (`expr "||" expr`), so something like `<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '84.x.x.x" || "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '85.x.x.x">`

Comment: Tried it, error 500

`[Wed Jun 28 17:31:14.880016 2017] [core:alert] [pid 18867:tid 140251697645312] [client 84.x:x] /home/x/domains/my.x.com/private_html/admin/.htaccess: Cannot parse condition clause: Unterminated string or variable, referer: https://my.x.com/admin/networkissues.php?action=manage`

Comment: I'd say that is because of the obvious syntax error your code already contains (which indeed I did not fix, thinking it was a simple typo here, sorry for that). So have a try with: `<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '84.x.x.x'" || "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '85.x.x.x'">`...

Comment: Thanks I see the typo and have edited the question. However this typo was not present in the actual code. Unfortunately your latest suggestion still gives error 500. 

I have some promising progress on doing it without the if statement. But if you can find a fix for the <if method then that would be very cool.

Comment: I do _not_ get an internal error for that condition. Please check your http servers error log file for the _exact_ issue you actually face. The information visualized in the browser is not enough for this.

Comment: From var/log/httpd/domains/x.err.log

`[Wed Jun 28 17:45:00.148209 2017] [core:alert] [pid 22524:tid 139672399271680] [client 84.104.129.37:54261] /home/x/domains/x.x.com/private_html/admin/.htaccess: Multiple <If> arguments not supported.`

Comment: As said: works for me. But you might also want to try using a regular expression, also possible according to the documentation: `<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m#(85.x.x.x)|(86.x.x.x)#">`

Comment: Ok great, latest revision is working (of course had to add the !)

`<If "! %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m#(84.x.x.x)|(85.x.x.x)#">`

If you post it as answer then I can mark it as best answer.

Comment: Sure, added a short answer covering this option.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use the 'IN' operator :
You can find some example here :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/expr.html

```
    # Check a HTTP header for a list of values
<If "%{HTTP:X-example-header} in { 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' }">
    Header set matched true
</If>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthName "no public access"
AuthUserFile /home/x/domains/my.x.com/.htpasswd/public_html/test/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
#location1
Allow from 84.x.x.x
#location2
Allow from 185.x.x.x
Satisfy Any
```

It is using completely different syntax, so therefore this is not a 100% answer to my original question. However it does allow for multiple IP to be whitelisted on a password protected directory.

Comment: Sure, that is the 2.2 syntax and directive set. You stated in your question that this is _not_ what you want.

Comment: You are 100% correct it does not answer my original question. I still like to share this code though, since it does prove a working alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry new account/ So can't add comment to the correct answer.

Just one mistake has been made in previous answers. Since Magistar wants to capture if it is not those IP's Félicien's answer should be(Note !):

```
# Check a HTTP header for a list of values
<If  "! %{HTTP:REMOTE_ADDR} in { '84.x.x.x', '85.x.x.x' } ">
    Header set matched true
</If>
```

Additionally if you wanted to use single expressions you should have needed &&(AND) not ||(OR):

```
<If "!(%{REMOTE_ADDR} = '84.x.x.x' && %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '85.x.x.x')">
```

The reason it might not have worked is because the whole expression should have been between one large double quoted blocked.

I do find Félicien's answer more *neat* then multiple expressions though.

Comment: Unfortunately the check header example is not whitelisting my IP properly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using a regular expression based comparison:

```
<If "! %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m#(85.x.x.x)|(86.x.x.x)#">
```

This allows to compare the address against a pattern which offers huge flexibility.